# What happens internally when an akka.conf file is read?

Tags: akka, actor, ignite, opendaylight, akka-persistence

I am using OpenDaylight and trying to replace the default distributed database with Apache Ignite.
I am using the jar obtained by using the source code here: 
https://github.com/Romeh/akka-persistance-ignite and deployed it in OpenDaylight karaf container.

The following is a portion of the akka.conf file i am using in OpenDaylight to replace the LevelDB journal with Apache Ignite.

```
odl-cluster-data {
  akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"

    default-dispatcher {
      # Configuration for the fork join pool
       fork-join-executor {
        # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
        parallelism-min = 2
        # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
        parallelism-factor = 2.0
        # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
        parallelism-max = 10
      }
      # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
      # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
       # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
       throughput = 10
    }
  }

  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "10.145.59.44"
      port = 2551
   }
  }

  cluster {
     seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://test@127.0.0.1:2551"
    ]
     min-nr-of-members = 1
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
   }



# Disable legacy metrics in akka-cluster.
 akka.cluster.metrics.enabled=off

akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.ignite"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot.ignite"


   extensions = ["akka.persistence.ignite.extension.IgniteExtensionProvider"]



   persistence {
     # Ignite journal plugin
     journal {
       ignite {
         # Class name of the plugin
         class = "akka.persistence.ignite.journal.IgniteWriteJournal"
     plugin-dispatcher = "ignite-dispatcher"
         cache-prefix = "akka-journal"
         // Should be based into the the dara grid topology
        cache-backups = 1
         // if ignite is already started in a separate standalone grid where journal cache is already created
         cachesAlreadyCreated = false
      }
    }

    # Ignite snapshot plugin
    snapshot {
      ignite {
        # Class name of the plugin
        class = "akka.persistence.ignite.snapshot.IgniteSnapshotStore"
    plugin-dispatcher = "ignite-dispatcher"
        cache-prefix = "akka-snapshot"
        // Should be based into the the dara grid topology
        cache-backups = 1
        // if ignite is already started in a separate standalone grid where snapshot cache is already created
        cachesAlreadyCreated = false
      }
    }
  }

   }


}
```

However, the class IgniteWriteJournal does not seem to load which i have checked by putting some print statements in its constuructor as follows.

```
 public IgniteWriteJournal(Config config) throws NotSerializableException {
        System.out.println("!@#$% inside IgniteWriteJournal constructor\n");
        ActorSystem actorSystem = context().system();
         serializer = SerializationExtension.get(actorSystem).serializerFor(PersistentRepr.class);
         storage = new Store<>(actorSystem);

        JournalCaches journalCaches = journalCacheProvider.apply(config, actorSystem);
        sequenceNumberTrack = journalCaches.getSequenceCache();
        cache = journalCaches.getJournalCache();
}
```

So what exactly happens to the class that is mentioned in the akka.persistence.journal.ignite tag? Does the constructor of that class get called? What exactly happens in the background when the akka.conf file is read?

Answer (score 0):

Where are looking for the print outs - in data/log/karaf.log? System.out.println doesn't go there - use an org.slf4j.Logger.

How did you rebuild the IgniteWriteJournal source and deploy the new artifact? Are you sure your changes were actually deployed?

Comment: The print statements were to be displayed in the Apache Karaf console.
Apart from these print lines, the source code has some log lines like -
\\\\\\\\\\\  
    log.debug("doAsyncReplayMessages with params persistenceId: '{}' :fromSequenceNr {} :toSequenceNr {} :max{}",persistenceId, fromSequenceNr, toSequenceNr, max);
             ////////// These log lines are not present in karaf.log
I rebuilt the new artifact using Maven build and hot deployed it in karaf. I am sure these changes are working because the print statements in the extension class are printing in the Karaf console.